# How do I implement a custom buildr task defined externally?

Tags: ruby, rake-task, buildr, buildr-extension

I have a task which I'm trying to refactor into an external module so that I can later separate it from this project and use it for other projects.

When I try to run my task, I get an error:

```
Buildr aborted!
NoMethodError : undefined method `path_to' for nil:NilClass
```

Essentially it seems like the code for the `project.task` block is never called.

The code is as follows. Some of the code comes from the working code for the compile task, so I know that *those* bits are probably correct. Other parts come from documented examples for buildr, which from experience earlier today can be taken with a grain (or sometimes an entire lake) of salt. I can't figure out what I've done wrong, though.

```
module MacAppBundle
  include Buildr::Extension

  class MacAppBundleTask < Rake::Task
    attr_accessor :app_name

    def initialize(*args)
      super

      enhance do |task|
        #TODO: @project is always nil here because associate_with is never called
        app = @project.path_to("target/#{app_name}.app")
        if File.exists?(app)
          FileUtils.rm_rf(app)
        end
        Dir.mkdir(app)
        #... omitting copying the rest of the stuff into the bundle ...
      end
    end

  protected

    def associate_with(project)
      @project = project
    end
  end

  before_define do |project|
    mac_app_bundle = MacAppBundleTask.define_task('mac_app_bundle')

    project.task 'mac_app_bundle' do |task|
      #TODO: This code never executes. Why?
      mac_app_bundle.send :associate_with, project
      project.local_task('mac_app_bundle')
    end
  end

  after_define do |project|
    #TODO: This bit is definitely questionable because I can't find any documentation
    # or working examples of similar code.
    task('mac_app_bundle' => project.package(:jar))
  end

  def mac_app_bundle
    task('mac_app_bundle')
  end
end

class Buildr::Project
  include MacAppBundle
end

#TODO: Find a place to move this. Seems weird to have to call it in global scope.
Project.local_task('mac_app_bundle') do |name|
  puts "Creating Mac OS X app bundle for #{name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way appears to be:

```
  before_define do |project|
    mac_app_bundle = MacAppBundleTask.define_task('mac_app_bundle')
    mac_app_bundle.send :associate_with, project
    project.task('mac_app_bundle')
  end
```